# What is the best method to being able to sing again?

Tags: voice

I used to be able to sing and loved to with all my heart but after having neck surgery in 2007 it caused problems with the one muscle that effects the vocal cord. I've tried many times over the years to sing and I get like a charlie horse in my neck and causes severe pain. I want to be able to sing again. I was self taught so I don't know all the vocal lingo. It was the one gift that was taken from me that hurts the most. Loved singing songs by Whitney Houston, Patsy Cline and church music. It kills me every time I try and receive nothing but pain. I even get jealous of my daughter, who like me, has the gift of singing. I would never tell her though. I continue to help her the best I can. Any help would be greatly appreciated as I'm not ready to admit this is over for me.

Comment: Throat musculature is often such a fickle thing that I would hesitate to even recommend anything. Have you spoken with a doctor?

Comment: I talked to about it years ago and she had put me on a muscle relaxer flexeral but it wasn't enough. I had to drop out of choir.

Answer (score 2):

can't you even sing softly?

if you can talk, you can probably sing softly.

be content with that.  work your way back up the volume scale slowly.  if there's no pain, keep going.  If there is pain, back off and just be happy with where you're at.

Answer (score 0):

Please do not take the adivce of random people on the internet on this. You need to get a properly qualified medical opinion from a doctor who's actually examined you (possibly the surgeon who operated on you?) and, if they say it's safe for you to do so, then see a vocal coach or speech therapist with specific experience in this area, not just any old singing teacher.

As Stephen says, if you can talk then you can probably still sing, but if there is any pain at all when singing then something is not right, and nobody can diagnose the problem at a distance. Whatever you do, do not be tempted to push through the pain.

Comment: I can talk just fine but I can't even hum a song. It's really depressing and hard to be happy with what I got when I can't even manage to hum a tune and used to being able to sing any song I liked. I love music and I loved to sing. To have that gift ripped away is not something I can be happy with. I used to sing to my kids and now have a grandbaby coming and I want to be able to sing to him or her.

Comment: That must be very difficult for you. Do seek out medical advice - your general practitioner should be able to point you in the right direction. If you can talk then there's reason to hope that you may be able to learn to sing again with help from an experienced teacher, but there are some people who do lose their singing voices altogether and that must take some adjusting to. Don't give up hope until you've explored all the possibilities, and best of luck with it!